# Pre-load videos and cache them - swift

Tags: swift, url, caching, avplayer, browser-cache

I have collectionView and each cell has a video displayed.

When a cell is tapped I present a ViewController that plays the video.

The code that does this in the ViewController is as follows:

```
fileprivate func configureVideo(with moment : Moment){
    guard let urlString = moment.videoUrl else { return }
    guard let videoUrl = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    self.player = AVPlayer(url: videoUrl)
    
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    
    self.player!.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(player.currentItem.isPlaybackLikelyToKeepUp),
                             options: .new, context: &playbackLikelyToKeepUpContext)
    
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(videoReachedEnd), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
    
    self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(playerLayer!, at: 0)
    self.playerLayer?.frame = self.view.bounds
    self.player?.play()
}
```

The fact that the video is being loaded when the controller is presented makes the process of video loading longer than I would like it to.

I would like that the videos are being loaded before, when I am scrolling through the cells of the collectionView, so that when I tap on a cell and the controller is presented, the video is already ready to play.

But I don't know what would be the right approach for it.
If you have any suggestions I am willing to listen.

Comment: You might need to add items in your collection view to a AVQueuePlayer.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more what you mean?

Comment: Here's the idea: each item in your collection view contains a video url, create a AVPlayerItem based on that and add them all to AVQueuePlayer. Then when user selects an item from collection view, pass the corresponding player item to the player VC.

Comment: perfect! Now I understand, tomorrow I'll try this solution thank you very much :)

Comment: Couldn't I have an array of AVplayerItem in the collectionViewViewController and just pass the AVPlayerItem to the ViewController when presented instead of using AVQueuePlayer?
Is there any difference? @Asteroid

Comment: @Asteroid I construct an array of AVPlayers when the collectionView is scrolling and when the cell is tapped I pass the already created AVPlayer to the controller presented.
It works fine, thank you!

Comment: @StackGU do you have an example? if yes, then send me. thanks in advance.

Comment: @JaydeepVirani an example of what?

Comment: @StackGU as you told solutions, so I want that if you have an example then please send me.

Comment: @JaydeepVirani Basically the idea is this:

The controller that displays the collectionView holds an array of `AVPlayers`.
Something like this `var players = [AVPlayer]()`

When a `collectionView cell` is being tapped in the `didSelectItemAt` method, you configure the other viewcontroller with a player from the array players.
Something like this:
`func configureController(playerPassed: AVPlayer?)`

In this way you are able to pass an already loaded `AVPlayer` to the next controller without waiting for it to load the video